# how to create image chooser in Croogo cms?

Tags: image, content-management-system, cakephp-2.0, croogo

How to create an input form like Example chooser in Croogo Example plugin such that when we insert an image after selecting the image , it's url gets inserted in input textbox.?
I have created this, but when i click on the insert icon (image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngTav.jpg)), it's url does not get inserted in textbox.

Comment: Can you explain this with a visual example..? It will help...

Comment: i want with click on insert icon, image address insert in image textbox